# How to wait for the files to upload in the following function?

Tags: javascript, upload

The following function loops through a schema (recursively). If the field is a file input then `api.uploadPhoto` is called. If the field is not one, then the value of the field is just assigned to `buildingPayload`:

```
handleUpdateBuilding () {
  const buildingPayload = {}
  this.buildingForm.schema.forEach(field => {
    if (utils.hasUploadFiles(field)) { // FOR FILE INPUTS
      api.uploadPhoto(field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
        buildingPayload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto
      })
    } else { // FOR THE REST OF THE INPUTS
      buildingPayload[field.name] = field.value
    }
  })
  this.updateBuilding(buildingPayload)
}
```

There's a problem: `this.updateBuilding(buildingPayload)` is called *before*  `api.uploadPhoto(file, field)` finishes with all the files.

How to modify `handleUpdateBuilding` so it waits for every file to be uploaded before calling `this.updateBuilding(buildingPayload)`?

Comment: `field => {
    else if` that looks ... odd

Comment: You'll need to wait on **all** the Promises to resolve - so `Promise.all` is a likely candidate - I'd show how, but `.eachCall`? `.eachDeep`? and that funky `else if` make your code hard to undertand

Comment: @JaromandaX I made the code more redeable.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use Promise.all and rather than .forEach use .map and return the promises

```
handleUpdateBuilding () {
    const buildingPayload = {};
    Promise.all(this.buildingForm.schema.map(field => {
        if (utils.hasUploadFiles(field)) { // FOR FILE INPUTS
            return api.uploadPhoto(field).then(uploadedPhoto => buildingPayload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto);
        } else { // FOR THE REST OF THE INPUTS
            buildingPayload[field.name] = field.value;
            return; // not a promise, but Promise.all handles that
        }
    })).then(() => this.updateBuilding(buildingPayload));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `this.updateBuilding(buildingPayload)` is still running before `api.uploadPhoto(field)` is ready.

Comment: oh, wait, perhaps a little "fix"

Comment: if that doesn't fix it, that would suggest that the promise returned by `api.uploadPhoto` is resolving "too early"